# creating product with variations using woocommerce REST API

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I've created a product with variations but they are not linked at the back end and won't show up on the product page unless i manually set them[image]

```
$data = [
'title'=> 'ship your idea5',

'type' => 'variable',
'description' => 'Trying it out for real',
'short_description' => 'Pellentesque habitant.',
'categories' => [
    [
        'name' => 'Movies',
        'slug' => 'movies'
    ],
    [
        'name' => 'Romance',
        'slug' => 'romance'
    ]
],
'images' => [
    [
        'src' => 'http://demo.woothemes.com/woocommerce/wp-content/uploads/sites/56/2013/06/T_4_front.jpg',
        'position' => 0
    ]

],
'attributes' => [
    [
        'name' => 'Color',
        'position' => 0,
        'visible' => true,
        'variation' => true,
        'options' => [
            'Black',
            'Green'
        ]
    ],
    [
        'name' => 'Size',
        'position' => 0,
        'visible' => true,
        'variation' => true,
        'options' => [
            'S',
            'M'
        ]
    ]
],
'default_attributes' => [
    [
        'name' => 'Color',
        'option' => 'Black'
    ],
    [
        'name' => 'Size',
        'option' => 'S'
    ]
    ],
    'variations' => array( 
        array(  'regular_price' => '29.98', 
        'attributes' => array( 
            array( 'name'=>'Color', 'options'=>'Black' )
             ) 
            ),
             array(  'regular_price' => '29.98',
              'attributes' => array( 
                  array( 'name'=>'color', 'options'=>'Green' ) 
                  ) 
                  ) 
                  )


];


$client->products->create($data);
```

any help is highly appreciated

Comment: Inside variations => attributes it should be **option** instead of **options**

Comment: Are you able to set categories by this code? I have figured out most of it but still stuck on categories

Comment: @PiyushRawat no not yet still working on setting categories too but for the variations,  i've done some research and i think there is no way of doing it in  the same request because variations have a different dedicated end point as according to the API docs. but i'll keep working if i get and answer i'll update you

Comment: I got it fixed bro...look here https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/286732/add-products-to-woocommerce-through-wp-api

Comment: yea this is great, i've also tried adding product with php and its possible to do in one request but the categories won't work i don't know why

Comment: do the categories exist already? or are you trying to create them with products?

Comment: categories already exist

Answer (score 1):

you have to create another request for variation.

```
$variation_data = [
    'regular_price' => '15.00',
    'image'         => [
        'src' => 'https://shop.local/path/to/image_size_l.jpg',
    ],
    'attributes'    => [
        [
            'id'     => 5,
            'option' => 'L',
        ],
    ],
];

$this->woocommerce->post( "products/$product->id/variations", $variation_data );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use variations/batch and used your existing product attributes
/wp-json/wc/v3/products//variations/batch
[image]

Comment: Please don't use images to show your code examples.

Comment: in rest api json/wc/v3/products//variations/batch check here example use this you its same as added image example